# Spf A record for a second domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf, txt-record

I need to use this spf record on example.com domain:

```
example.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:smtp.second.net -all"
```

I'd like to know if a client sending an email from `bob@example.com` domain will pass the spf check if they use `smtp.second.net` smtp server.

Smtp.second.net ip address is not listed on an A record of example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mkgl - In technical terms, it depends.

1. If bob@example.com is sending mail from the example.com (IP Address). Then it will pass
2. If bob@example.com is sending mail from a different IP, then it won't even use the Example SPF to validate against (since it's not the sending IP).

Remember the SPF is the 5321.FROM which is the "Return-Path" not the "From" on the email.

The SPF that's being looked up is the "Received IP" in the header (Which is the last sending IP) - So if the email is not being sent from the example.com IP address (It won't even use the example.com IP SPF)

If you're really not sure about the mechanics of SPF, use this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) to check whether or not your SPF Passes. It a simple world, it works, but it's all depends on how you are sending mail.

Comment: The Mail Tester tool was very useful, but  the report shows a "Return-Path" email that belongs to example.com.  The spf checked is for example.com domain.
The mail is delivered through two second.net servers as shown on the "Mail Flow".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work, because you specifically list such server as allowed through the `a:` specification.